# Using while: reverse printing

Tags: python

Doing python exercises already I've a problem with string:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = 'mandarino'
indice = len(str)-1
#print ("indice is:",indice)

while indice > 0:
        lett = str[indice]
        print (lett)
        indice = indice -1
```

Putting off "-1" the results is:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Gives me no error :/

Comment: @BhargavRao, I think OP meant removing `-1` from `indice = len(str) - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
indice = indice - 1
```

and change:

```
while indice > 0:
```

to

```
while indice >= 0:
```

so the script will be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

str = 'mandarino'
indice = len(str)
indice = indice - 1
#print ("indice is:",indice)

while indice >= 0:

        lett = str[indice]
        print (lett)
        indice = indice -1
```

Better and handy:

```
indice = len(str)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while indice > 0:
```

should be

```
while indice >= 0:
```

to print the first character (index `0`) at last.

---

BTW, if you use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), you don't need to calculate index yourself:

```
s = 'mandarino'
for ch in reversed(s):
    print(ch)
```

Side note: Don't use `str` as a varaible name. It will shadow a built in function/type [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: @PolHallen I guess you removed `-1` also. Only then you'll get an error, else falsetru's answer is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Though above answers are correct..this is more `pythonic` way...

```
string = 'mandarino'
indice = len(string)

while indice >= 0:
    indice -= 1
    print (string[indice]),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also treat strings as list of characters and using reverse indexing, this way:

```
>>> str1 = 'mandarino'
>>> for ch in str1[::-1]:
    print ch


o
n
i
r
a
d
n
a
m
```